# Cross platform GUI with a comfortable IDE and GUI designer (Windows/Linux/OS X) and information visualization libraries?

Tags: c#, java, user-interface, frameworks, cross-platform

I've been struggling to find a framework/IDE/GUI designer that suits my current needs. I'm working on a project which has the following criteria:

- .NET / Java are OK but I'm a C/C# developer mainly. I have little experience with Java toolkits.
- I need something along the lines of prefuse (http://prefuse.org) for information visualization.
- I need a large collection of 'ready to go' components. .NET / Java see the most widely extended use. Things like a VNC control or library, graphing, etc.
- Portability over looks, I need something comfortable to use, and a GUI designer.
- All components of the IDE must work fine on Windows 7 64-bit. Or Linux amd64.

So far I tested:

- Eclipse with SWT + Visual Editor: broken 64bit support, the 32bit one truly works horrible. I can't seem to find the toolbox of controls etc, and everything is dumped into the Java Beans menu. I'm also a total noob with Java GUI code. I would like to have something half as epic as prefuse for visualization, though, for .NET.
- Lots of experience with .NET, but I am not sure I would be able to interact all the components in Mono for instance. Compatibility issues would suck... so I'm kind of out of luck.

Let me know.

Comment: If you are looking for a RAD based IDE for Java, I would recommend giving Netbeans a try.

Comment: I have built a few large Java projects that target 32-bit and 64-bit Window OS using Eclipse IDE. Java is a good choice if you want a large library support (commercial or open-source). For Java GUI component library that is portable, use Swing instead of SWT. About visualization library Prefuse, it also supports GUI Swing components. You can use JUNG2 but it is meant for a different purpose. For Eclipse IDE, the best GUI editor so far is Jigloo GUI editor. I never use Visual Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Netbeans and love it. Simple to use and uses Swing not SWT for its GUI's which should get you 100% cross platform support.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Qt: http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use mono.

I know, you have the link, but I need more characters to post, so I repeat it here: http://mono-project.com

Comment: If Mono is your choice, then MonoDevelop would go quite well with it.

Comment: Mono is amateur-ish. It has no acceptance in certain enterprise level circles and for me it is 100% out of the picture / can't consider. WinForms is also in par with old school Swing. Funny enough it only does native drawing on Windows.

Comment: @soze thanks for your opinion. I suggest to start learning it. You wont regret :)

Comment: @user492238 You don't learn "Mono". It's a MSIL vm, no more no less. There is nothing special about it differing from specification .NET. It works for certain projects without huge requirements, but for me it's useless. At enterprise level you want to be productive, not mingle around with software to reach a point where it is mature enough to use for your purposes. It already has to be mature enough.

Comment: @soze which problems did you encounter? Or is it just that you decide in an early pre-production state to not use it? So I would suggest, to give it another try ;)